# Should I keep all the articles in rss or just the new ones?

Tags: rss, feed

Should I keep all the articles in rss feed or just new ones? There are too many articles on my website and a new one is added in every 10-20 minutes so what would be the best approach in this case. Keep all the entries and just add new ones or add new ones and delete old ones at the same time??? If the second is better how many entries should I keep?

Comment: keep everything. would be my decision.
i think you need ask your questino a bit more detailed, 
but in any case why would you delete articles?
one every 10-20 minutes doesnt so bad. i cant imagine use case where this could cause problems! thats not so much data... just put the right indexes in your database and stuff.
assuming of course your question is programming related.
or are you talking about your local xml reader or what content to deliver to your users? ... then this is the wrong place for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If new articles are added every 10-20 minutes, then after an hour you'll have 3-6, after a day you'll have 72-144, after a week you'll have around 500-1000, and after a month you'll have several thousand entries in your RSS feed. This is quickly going to become a multi-megabyte download, which is crazy unwieldy.

I think most desktop RSS readers can be configured for how often they should check for updates, and for a feed with this kind of traffic, most users would probably set their reader to check once an hour, or maybe even every 15 minutes. Online readers (like Google Reader) don't always have an option for how often to update, but I think they adapt -- they see how often new entries are added, and automatically check more often for a feed they've noticed is high-traffic.

Given that, if you put about a day's worth of entries in your feed -- for example, the most recent 100 -- that would probably be great plenty.

Answer (score 1):

Keep them as long as possible, cos you don't know how regularly your readers grab the RSS.

What if you drop old articles every 30 mins and I only check every 24 hours? I'll miss so many!